# Describe the coordinates of all points that are 10 units from the yz plane.

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

I don't really understand the y and z coordinates.

I know i will have a +/- 10 as the x-value, and the point will be located at the front right above the origin quadrant (is there a better way to word this?)

not to sure about the y and z?

any help appreciated :)

Comment: Let's put this in perspective. Let's go back to 2 dimensions. Consider the x-axis. Now can you tell the locus of all point that are 10 units away from the x-axis? That could be 10 above (so $y=10$) or 10 below (that's $y=-10$). So the answer is two lines, parallel with the x-axis inbetween. Now can you translate this into 3D where inbetween there is a plane?

Comment: how are the two lines parallel?

Comment: also in the yz plane, why must x equal zero???

Comment: Because the x-axis is a line at y=0, right? We want to find the set of all points that are 10 units away from the line.  What does this tell you? That all such points are on the lines running along the x axis, 10 units above OR below it.  Since the slopes are the same, they are parallel - if the lines were slanted, would they still be 10 units from the x-axis?

x is zero only when we're talking about the yz plane, because we only want points on there - we don't want any x.  If x=0, we're restricting the degrees of freedom to the y and z coordinates.

Comment: hmm that makes sense, but how would i describe the y and z values 10 units away?

Answer (score 1):

So in 3D, =f $x=10$ then (10,0,0) is a point that lies 10 unit away from the yx plane. 
But (10,5,8) also lies 10 unit away from the yz plane. In fact, (10,y,z) is 10 units away from the yz plane. General point (10,y,z) is on one "side" of the yz plane. So $x=10$ would be the equation of one plane satisfying the condition. What general point is exactly on the other side?